# Need formula to determine # of membership visits remaining based on past check-ins

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula to give me X. X = # of remaining visits. For example, membership level includes 8 visits a month. When the user has 2 visits left, I want to send them an email. Data I'm collecting includes dates of previous check-ins and original join date. The tricky part is, each member's join date is different and is not the 1st of the month so the number of remaining check-ins needs to take into account their join date + 30 days, then count their number of check-ins within that period of time and then keep track of their check-ins as the month progresses, always indicating how many check-ins used and how many check-ins remain in future 30 day windows.

[image]

[sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1URWXLs-7TLuEOe8QES1OQpUZUFlsG7Tk9nWvmOenoSQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would also be useful to include sample data in your question and not just as a link.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the link is of sample data

Comment: @NadiaCharles a question should be able to stand on its own with a link that may or may not be there a year from now.  Questions are kept open for future visitors who may have a similar problem.  By using a link to define the question you are making it impossible for future readers to gain any reference.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, my bad, I tried pasting the spreadsheet data but it just came out as text and I kept getting an error when submitting my question so just send the link.

Comment: @ScottCraner understood and I'll happily paste it spreadsheet in my question but I could not figure out how to paste a spreadsheet in the "code" section of my question.

Comment: Take a screen shot of it and post it on Imgur.  Then [edit] the post to include the link.  Someone with enough rep will edit to add the photo to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in H2 and copy down:

```
=COUNTIFS(F:F,">="&E2+INT((F2-E2)/30)*30,F:F,"<"&E2+(INT((F2-E2)/30)+1)*30,B:B,B2)
```